# Running a Standard and Flexible environment in the same cloud intance

Tags: google-app-engine-python

Can I run a Python standard app engine instance along with another Python flexible app engine instance in the same Google Cloud instance?

I know this sounds unusual; I don't want to get into the why's. Just wondering if it's at all possible, and if so, how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have different versions of the same service/module using different runtimes. You can also have different modules/services in the same Google Cloud project running different app engine runtimes.

You can access the different versions like this: https://versionName-dot-serviceName-dot-projectName.appspot.com/